# .NET webcam video capture to file

Tags: .net, video, webcam, video-capture

I'm looking for a solution to record video from webcam in .NET. Currently, I'm using VideoLab components (http://mitov.com/html/directshow_video_capture_in__n.html). It works, however it has some annoying bugs or incompatibility with my device. Moreover, it's a bit heavyweight for my simple task. All I need is recording to file from default webcam with starting and stopping controls. Is there any simple solution available?

Answer (score 0):

Well...one solution would be [DirectShow.NET](http://directshownet.sourceforge.net/), but it's lower-level than the VideoLab components, so it might be more complicated but you would have much more control.